# loop array and assigned the key and value and format based on value: php

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with api with laravel/php and I need the data in following format. It would be great if you can help me or give some hint.

if I do dd() $formData which is submitted from the form I get following array

```
dd($formData);
```

dd($formData) gives below result

```
array:3 [▼
  "fname" => "john"
  "lname" => "doe"
  "age" => "22"

]
```

Now, Since the $`formData` array length is 3, I need three array and their `key` should be assigned to `field_name`,`value` should be assigned to `value` and based on value it should be either `text`, `number` or `date`. Number if value is `numeric`, date if value is in format 2010-12-01 or 2010/12/01.dd/mm/yyyy otherwise it will be `text`

Now I need an array that return data in below format.
$formData to $newFormData and $newFormData should have following data

output:

```
 [
      'field_name' => 'fname',
      'value_type' => 'text', //should be text if value is  not number or date format
      'value' => 'john',
  ],
  [
      'field_name' => 'lname',
      'value_type' => 'text',//should be text if value is not  number or date
      'value' => 'doe',
  ],
  [
      'field_name' => 'age',
      'value_type' => 'number',//should be number if value is  numeric
      'value' => '22',
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use laravel [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) for this use case with the [map](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map) method.

```
$formData = [
    "fname" => "john",
    "lname" => "doe",
    "age" => "22",
    "date" => "2010-12-01",
];
$result = collect($formData)->map(function ($value, $key) {
    return [
        'field_name' => $key,
        'value' => $value,
        'value_type' => getValueType($value),
    ];
})->values();
```

and here the `getValueType` function:

```
function getValueType($value)
{
    if (is_numeric($value)) return 'number';
    $isDate = true;
    try {
        Carbon\Carbon::parse($value);
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        $isDate = false;
    }
    if ($isDate) return 'date';
    return 'text';
}
```

If you would like to have a plain PHP array in the `$result` variable, then you can add `->toArray()` after `->values()`.

Comment: "value" => "14/09/2010 ,date I am getting text instead of date format

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the result as empty array

```
$result = [];
```

Loop through the form data

```
foreach($formData as $key => $data){
    $tempData['field_name'] = $key;
    $tempData['value_type'] = retrieveValueType($data);
    $tempData['value'] = $data;
    $result[] = $tempData; //Append array to object
}
```

Creating a function to retrieve the value type

```
function retrieveValueType($value){
    if(is_numeric($value)){
        return 'numeric';
    }else{
        $isDateValid = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $value);
        if($isDateValid){
            return 'date';
        }
        return 'text';
    }
}
```

It will provide the result as you require

```
^ array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "field_name" => "fname"
    "value_type" => "text"
    "value" => "john"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "field_name" => "lname"
    "value_type" => "text"
    "value" => "doe"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "field_name" => "age"
    "value_type" => "number"
    "value" => "22"
  ]
]
```

Comment: thanks @Lizesh, how to assign value type data if it is in date format . here    $tempData['value_type'] = is_numeric($data) ? 'number' : 'text'; currently we can say if it is not number, default as a text. but if the value is in format dd-mm-yyyy it should be date not number or text. thanks

Comment: Edited as per your requirement

Comment: for "value" => "14/09/2010" date I am getting value_type text instead of date

Comment: Change the value of 'd-m-Y'  in `retrieveValueType()` function as per your preference. For now, putting 'd/m/Y' will solve the issue.

Comment: yes done the same thing but still same, showing text         $isDateValid = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $value); also done         $isDateValid = DateTime::createFromFormat('dd/mm/yyyy', $value);